# On a scroll to activate animation event, how to make the animation NOT to play again when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

In my website, I have a series of animated full width blocks that will be activated on a scrolling event, the problem is that the animation will play again if the user decides to scroll up to the previous block, how can I make each block to stay once the animation is played during the first time scrolling down event? Thanks! 
Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/basurayu/5RNhL/670/), any help will be much appreciated!

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animatedelements');
var $window = $(window);

var cont = 0;
const MULTIPLIER = 300; //millis

function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height + 15);

  $.each($animation_elements, function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {


      if($element.is($('div').parent()) && !$element.hasClass('fadeInUp')) {
        cont++;
        var delay = MULTIPLIER * cont;

        $element.addClass('fadeInUp');
        //Pause animation.
        $element.addClass('paused');

        setTimeout(function() {
          //Start animation
          $element.removeClass('paused');
          cont--;
        }, delay);
      }else {
        $element.addClass('fadeInUp');
      }
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('fadeInUp');
    }
  });
}

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: So should each animation happen only once at all, or if the user scrolls back up to the top and then scrolls down again should the animations repeat?

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn, thank you so much for the reply, I would like the animations to play again if the user scrolls back up to the top and go back again. However, if that is too hard, playing once at all is fine too, thank you :)

Comment: Well if you remove the `$element.removeClass('fadeInUp');` line the animations would only ever run once because only elements without that class get animated. You could then add a new `if` to the scroll event handler (before the existing `$.each()`) to test if the user has scrolled all the way to the top and if so call `$('.fadeInUp').removeClass('fadeInUp')` to reset all of the elements. (Sorry, I don't have time to write a proper answer now.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you again for your answer and time, I will go with playing only once for now, if you happen to have a little spare time in the future, could you kindly give me a little more guidance in the second case? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jessie: What is your 2nd case?

Comment: @iMatoria: the animation plays only once, but if the user scrolls back up to the top and then scrolls down again should the animations repeat. Thanks :)

Comment: Try removing `cont` variable and hardcode the time `setTimeout`.